# How to convert 2d np.array of lists of floats into a 2d np.array of floats, stacking the list values to rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a huge 2d numpy array of lists (dtype `object`) that I want to convert into a 2d numpy array of dtype `float`, stacking the dimension represented by lists onto the 0th axis (rows). The lists within each row always have the exact same length, and have at least one element.

Here is a minimal reproduction of the situation:

```
import numpy as np
current_array = np.array(
    [[[0.0], [1.0]], 
    [[2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0]]]
)
desired_array = np.array(
    [[0.0, 1.0], 
    [2.0, 4.0],
    [3.0, 5.0]]
)
```

I looked around for solutions, and `stack` and `dstack` functions work only if the first level is a tuple. `reshape` would require the third level to be a part of the array. I wonder, is there any relatively efficient way to do it?

Currently, I am just counting the dimensions, creating empty array and filling the values one by one, which honestly does not seem like a good solution.

Comment: The first list has an extra layer of nesting.  `np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0]])` would be easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, and this was fully intended. As I said I have a 2d np.array of lists (2d array of dtype object). You receive such an array using the code I posted. This is not my choice, but the input I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of the question here.

I found a slightly more elegant (and faster) way than filling the array one by one, which is:

```
desired = np.array([np.concatenate([np.array(d) for d in lis]) for lis in current.T]).T
print(desired)
'''
[[0. 1.]
 [2. 4.]
 [3. 5.]]
 '''
```

But it still does quite the number of operations. It transposes the table to be able to stack the neighboring 'dimensions' (one of them is the lists) with `np.concatenate`, and then converts the result to `np.array` and transposes it back.

Comment: Numpy transpose is cheap (though subsequent operations might require a copy).

Comment: Since there were no additional solutions and out of the two, this solution is faster, I will shamelessly accept this as an answer. (Thankfully SO doesn't give any points for doing that, just to be clear.)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [321]: current_array = np.array( 
     ...:     [[[0.0], [1.0]],  
     ...:     [[2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0]]] 
     ...: )                                                                     
In [322]: current_array                                                         
Out[322]: 
array([[list([0.0]), list([1.0])],
       [list([2.0, 3.0]), list([4.0, 5.0])]], dtype=object)
In [323]: _.shape                                                               
Out[323]: (2, 2)
```

Rework the two rows:

```
In [328]: current_array[1,:]                                                    
Out[328]: array([list([2.0, 3.0]), list([4.0, 5.0])], dtype=object)
In [329]: np.stack(current_array[1,:],1)                                        
Out[329]: 
array([[2., 4.],
       [3., 5.]])

In [330]: np.stack(current_array[0,:],1)                                        
Out[330]: array([[0., 1.]])
```

combine them:

```
In [331]: np.vstack((_330, _329))                                               
Out[331]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [2., 4.],
       [3., 5.]])
```

in one line:

```
In [333]: np.vstack([np.stack(row, 1) for row in current_array])                
Out[333]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [2., 4.],
       [3., 5.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try your solution. I would like to emphasize that the code I posted is a minimal example allowing for the reproduction of the problem. (The actual array is around 50x5000, while the list size varies between 160 and 500). Still, I can use the general outline you provided in a loop and check how it performs.